# Why probability of detection of optimum unambiguous discrimination between linearly independent symmetric states is less than random guess?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics

Considering the analysis and result of this paper, http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9807023v1.pdf, I have used equation (3.15) and (4.3) to calculate the optimum probability of success for mean photon number = 10000 and number of measurement basis= 2000, and got probability of success for detecting correct state is $6.19*10^-13$, which is much smaller than random guess($1/2000$).What is the reason behind this of getting such a small probability of success following a particular measurement scheme,which is even smaller than random guess(1/2000), and random guess means no measurement at all.